# Parse API output in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Apologies if it is very basic one , completely new to ruby.

Below is the sample response I am getting while using the curl , need to get the values of `body` , `created_at` from the below output .

When I tried to check type of the value , puts returns `true` for (string) and `false` for hash and array

```
`#puts value.is_a?(Hash)
#puts value.is_a?(Array)
#puts value.is_a?(String)`
```

Not sure how to get value from the below output , Please help on with the first step/idea need to do  here , will try on and revert back on getting any issues further

SAMPLE CALL
     `curl https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/qfn30z5r6s5h/incidents.json \
        -H "Authorization: OAuth 2a7b9d4aac30956d537ac76850f4d78de30994703680056cc103862d53cf8074"`

```
SAMPLE RESPONSE
  [
    {
      "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:45:33-06:00",
      "id": "tks5n8x7w24h",
      "impact": "none",
      "impact_override": null,
      "incident_updates": [
        {
          "body": "We will be performing a data layer migration from our existing Postgres system over to our new, multi-region, distributed Riak cluster. The application will be taken offline during the entirety of this migration. We apologize in advance for the inconvenience",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:45:33-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:45:33-06:00",
          "id": "kb4fpktpqm0l",
          "incident_id": "tks5n8x7w24h",
          "status": "scheduled",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:45:33-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false,
          "affected_components": [
            {
              "code": "ftgks51sfs2d",
              "name": "API",
              "old_status": "operational",
              "new_status": "operational"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        "jira": {
          "issue_id": "value"
        }
      ],
      "monitoring_at": null,
      "name": "Data Layer Migration",
      "page_id": "jcm87b8scw0b",
      "postmortem_body": null,
      "postmortem_body_last_updated_at": null,
      "postmortem_ignored": true,
      "postmortem_notified_subscribers": false,
      "postmortem_notified_twitter": false,
      "postmortem_published_at": null,
      "resolved_at": null,
      "scheduled_auto_in_progress": false,
      "scheduled_auto_completed": false,
      "scheduled_for": "2013-05-04T01:00:00-06:00",
      "scheduled_remind_prior": false,
      "scheduled_reminded_at": null,
      "scheduled_until": "2013-05-04T03:00:00-06:00",
      "shortlink": "",
      "status": "scheduled",
      "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:45:33-06:00"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:04:28-06:00",
      "id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
      "impact": "critical",
      "impact_override": null,
      "incident_updates": [
        {
          "body": "A postmortem analysis has been posted for this incident.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:42:31-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:42:31-06:00",
          "id": "dn051mnj579k",
          "incident_id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
          "status": "postmortem",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:42:31-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false
        },
        {
          "body": "The application has returned to it's normal performance profile. We will be following up with a postmortem about future plans to guard against additional master database failure.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:16:38-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T14:07:00-06:00",
          "id": "ppdqv1grhm64",
          "incident_id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
          "status": "resolved",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:36:15-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false,
          "affected_components": [
            {
              "code": "ftgks51sfs2d",
              "name": "API",
              "old_status": "degraded_performance",
              "new_status": "operational"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "body": "The slave database has been successfully promoted, but is running slow due to a cold query cache. The application is open and available for requests, but should will be performing in a degraded state for the next few hours. We will continue to monitor the situation.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:14:46-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:14:46-06:00",
          "id": "j7ql87ktwnys",
          "incident_id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
          "status": "monitoring",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:14:46-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false,
          "affected_components": [
            {
              "code": "ftgks51sfs2d",
              "name": "API",
              "old_status": "major_outage",
              "new_status": "degraded_performance"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "body": "The slave database is 60% through it's recovery process. We will provide another update once the application is back up.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:08:42-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:08:42-06:00",
          "id": "xzgd3y9zdzt9",
          "incident_id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
          "status": "identified",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:08:42-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false,
          "affected_components": [
            {
              "code": "ftgks51sfs2d",
              "name": "API",
              "old_status": "major_outage",
              "new_status": "major_outage"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "body": "The master database server could not boot due to a corrupted EBS volume. We are in the process of failing over to the slave database. ETA for the application recovering is 5 minutes.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:06:27-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:06:27-06:00",
          "id": "9307nsfg3dxd",
          "incident_id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
          "status": "identified",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:06:27-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false,
          "affected_components": [
            {
              "code": "ftgks51sfs2d",
              "name": "API",
              "old_status": "major_outage",
              "new_status": "major_outage"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "body": "We're investigating an outage with our master database server.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:04:28-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:04:28-06:00",
          "id": "dz959yz2nd4l",
          "incident_id": "cz46ym8qbvwv",
          "status": "investigating",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:04:29-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false,
          "affected_components": [
            {
              "code": "ftgks51sfs2d",
              "name": "API",
              "old_status": "operational",
              "new_status": "major_outage"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        "jira": {
          "issue_id": "value"
        }
      ],
      "monitoring_at": "2013-04-21T11:14:46-06:00",
      "name": "Master Database Failure",
      "page_id": "jcm87b8scw0b",
      "postmortem_body": "##### Issue\r\n\r\nAt approximately 17:02 UTC on 2013-04-21, our master database server unexpectedly went unresponsive to all network traffic. A reboot of the machine at 17:05 UTC resulted in a failed mount of a corrupted EBS volume, and we made the decision at that time to fail over the slave database.\r\n\r\n##### Resolution\r\n\r\nAt 17:12 UTC, the slave database had been successfully promoted to master and the application recovered enough to accept web traffic again. A new slave database node was created and placed into the rotation to guard against future master failures. The promoted slave database performed slowly for the next couple of hours as the query cache began to warm up, and eventually settled into a reasonable performance profile around 20:00 UTC.\r\n\r\n##### Future Mitigation Plans\r\n\r\nOver the past few months, we've been working on an overhaul to our data storage layer with a migration from a Postgres setup to a distributed, fault-tolerant, multi-region data layer using Riak. This initiative has been prioritized, and the migration will be performed in the coming weeks. We will notify our clients of the scheduled downtime via an incident on this status site, and via a blog post.",
      "postmortem_body_last_updated_at": "2013-04-21T17:41:00Z",
      "postmortem_ignored": false,
      "postmortem_notified_subscribers": false,
      "postmortem_notified_twitter": false,
      "postmortem_published_at": "2013-04-21T17:42:31Z",
      "resolved_at": "2013-04-21T14:07:00-06:00",
      "scheduled_auto_in_progress": false,
      "scheduled_auto_completed": false,
      "scheduled_for": null,
      "scheduled_remind_prior": false,
      "scheduled_reminded_at": null,
      "scheduled_until": null,
      "shortlink": "",
      "status": "postmortem",
      "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:42:31-06:00"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "2013-04-01T12:00:00-06:00",
      "id": "2ggpd60zvx3c",
      "impact": "none",
      "impact_override": null,
      "incident_updates": [
        {
          "body": "At approximately 6:55 PM, our network provider at ServerCo experienced a brief network outage at their New Jersey data center. The network outage lasted approximately 14 minutes, and all web requests during that time were not received. No data was lost, and the system recovered once the network outage at ServerCo was repaired.",
          "created_at": "2013-04-21T11:02:00-06:00",
          "display_at": "2013-04-21T11:02:00-06:00",
          "id": "mkfzp9swbk4z",
          "incident_id": "2ggpd60zvx3c",
          "status": "investigating",
          "twitter_updated_at": null,
          "updated_at": "2013-04-21T11:02:00-06:00",
          "wants_twitter_update": false
        }
      ],
      "metadata": [
        "jira": {
          "issue_id": "value"
        }
      ],
      "monitoring_at": null,
      "name": "Brief Network Outage",
      "page_id": "jcm87b8scw0b",
      "postmortem_body": null,
      "postmortem_body_last_updated_at": null,
      "postmortem_ignored": false,
      "postmortem_notified_subscribers": false,
      "postmortem_notified_twitter": false,
      "postmortem_published_at": null,
      "resolved_at": null,
      "scheduled_auto_in_progress": false,
      "scheduled_auto_completed": false,
      "scheduled_for": null,
      "scheduled_remind_prior": false,
      "scheduled_reminded_at": null,
      "scheduled_until": null,
      "shortlink": "",
      "status": "resolved",
      "updated_at": "2013-04-01T12:00:00-06:00"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JSON. Since you're using Rails, it will be sufficient to call

```
JSON.parse(value)
```

This will return an array of multiple hashes which you will be able to further map.

Comment: I tried `data_hash = JSON.parse(value)
puts data_hash.keys` but getting below error

`script:8:in `<main>': `undefined method` `keys' for #<Array:0x007ff52a965510> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Yes, you have an array of hashes, not a hash. If you want first "created_at", you can simply call `JSON.parse(value).first["created_at"]`. If you want all `created_at`, you can call `JSON.parse(value).map {|h| h["created_at"] }`. You will need to learn how to work with arrays and hashes in ruby.

Comment: I am getting the output now , Thank you so much .
will do the work on arrays and hashes , between please suggest good articles for arrays of hashes if any please